# I can't enter Croatia with my EU Digital COVID Certificate

Tags: eu, austria, croatia, vaccinations, covid-19

I already had COVID back in January, and therefore I got my EU Digital COVID Certificate, that is valid until end 27.07.2021. As I live in Austria and already had COVID, I should get only one dose of the vaccine. Last month I tried to get my vaccine, but they told me that I need to wait 6-8 months till I can get my shot.

In August, I'm going on a vacation to Croatia. Now, on the site of the Ministry of Croatia it states that you can enter if you have:

*certificate showing that they have recovered from COVID-19 and **have received one dose of vaccine within six months from contracting the disease**, provided that the vaccine was administered less than 210 days from their arrival at the border crossing point;*

So, that means, I can't enter with my EU Digital COVID Certificate, because I will be vaccinated more than 6 months after contracting COVID?

This does not make sense to me, because my certificate will not be valid if I don't get my first and only shot till 27.7.2021. But I can't do that, because I need to wait till at least 6 months have passed.

Comment: Welcome to bureaucracy, where left hand doesn't know what right hand is doing. This is life and we cannot do anything. EU complained about different interpretation between countries (and recommended to avoid them). Check if you can get a dose now in Austria (possibly now they have enough vaccines), and check everyday if some of the countries updated policies to be more consistent. But what is it your question?

Answer (score 2):

It means that you cannot qualify under that bullet point to enter Croatia.  But you can get a digital COVID certificate on the basis of a negative test.  Such certificates are valid for 48 or 72 hours, depending on the circumstances.  See https://gruenerpass.gv.at/getestet/:

> Ich bin getestet.
>
> Wie lange gilt mein Zertifikat in Österreich?
>
> Ein PCR-Test gilt 72 Stunden.
>
> Ein Antigen-Test, der in einer Teststraße oder Apotheke gemacht wird, gilt 48 Stunden.

Translation (from the website; it's not precisely the same in English as in German):

> I've been tested.
>
> How long is my certificate valid for?
>
> A PCR test is valid for 72 hours.
>
> An antigen test which is made at a testing site or at a pharmacy is valid for 48 hours.

Comment: I know that. It just makes me angry, that the EU can't come up with a plan, that all EU members would agree on.

Comment: @Andre It is simply up to each country to decide who will be vaccinated when. Independent of you having had Covid in January, still 62% of the Austrian population is not yet fully vaccinated and must also often present a negative test instead of a vaccination certificate when travelling.

Comment: @Andre Try going into a bar and tell the 27 customers that they must drink only what you thing they must drink and in a certain mannor. After that experience, you will no doubt have a better understanding. The European Union is a [Confederation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confederation) of member states and not a [Federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation), where a central goverment generally has much more to say in the determination of a common central policy.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: But the EU _does_ have the power to issue regulations and directives that the individual countries involved have no power to override, so why doesn't it do so in this case?

Comment: @Vikki Becase **public health** is an area of **supporting competences** where *the EU can only support, coordinate or complement the action of member countries. It has no power to pass laws and may not interfere with member countries’ ability to do so.* [Areas of EU action | European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/info/about-european-commission/what-european-commission-does/law/areas-eu-action_en)

Comment: @MarkJohnson: I bet they're kicking themselves about that decision now...

Comment: @Vikki the EU _is_ the member states.  Mark Johnson's analogy is illustrative, but a closer analogy would be "try going into a bar where the 27 customers are the members of a board of directors to which you report, and tell them..."  The EU can't take power over something unless the member states grant it.  Furthermore, a decision to take power over something is a delicate one, as it could increase pressure on the EU to break apart.